# How to set the necessary timezone in LocalTime

Tags: java, timezone, localtime

I have a database which has a movie schedule. Well, of course there are two such columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
    hall_movies_schedules_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hall_id  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    film_id  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    start_at TIME   NOT NULL,
    end_at   TIME   NOT NULL,
    date     DATE   NOT NULL,
    cost     INT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(hall_id) REFERENCES cinema_halls(hall_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(film_id) REFERENCES films(film_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (hall_movies_schedules_id)
);
```

I have entity in java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableName")
public class HallMoviesSchedule {

    ...
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "start_at")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    private LocalTime startAt;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "end_at")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    private LocalTime endAt;
    ...

}
```

But pulling information to my web page gives one hour less than is in the database for my region. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalTime` does not have `TimeZone`. You have to use `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but how then is it better to set my timezone, or rather where it set?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` also needs a *date*, which usually doesn't make sense for recurring schedules. (I'm assuming these are not specific instances of movie showings.)

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Where in the example would `LocalTime` have used a default time zone?

Answer (score 2):

## `OffsetTime`

There is also a class `OffsetTime`. But that class makes no sense to me and to other folks. I presume he class was included in *java.time* merely to provide a counterpart to such a type defined in the SQL standard. The type in SQL also makes no sense. I mention these types only for the sake of completeness; I do *not* recommend their use.

## `LocalTime`

For both `TIME` in standard SQL and `LocalTime` in Java, the value represents a time-of-day generically, without any concept of time zone or offset. So there should be no time zones involved in its storage. If you write twelve noon `12:00:00.0` to the database, you should get back twelve noon.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalTime ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalTime myLocalTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you are selling tickets to a particular showing of a movie in a cinema, you must combine that time of day with a date and a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now( z ).plusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTicket = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , myLocalTime , z ) ;
```

See that same moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdtTicket.toInstant() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But the most interesting thing is that I get time an hour earlier from the database. On the topic of combining time with date is a logical remark, I have a LocalDate field there.